# Difference Between Socket Types

Tags: python, sockets

Yes, I did already try to find information on this.

The Python socket documentation has this list of what I believe are protocols:

```
SO_*
socket.SOMAXCONN
MSG_*
SOL_*
IPPROTO_*
IPPORT_*
INADDR_*
IP_*
IPV6_*
EAI_*
AI_*
NI_*
TCP_*
```

What exactly do they do? Let's say I used

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_IP)
```

What does this do? I understand it's a raw socket, but does the IPPROTO_IP mean I have to construct everything? (i.e. the IP header down to the TCP to the data?)

The Python documentation says I can find information on the above in the Unix documentation on sockets, but I couldn't find the document. Anyone know where it is?

Comment: Yes, IPPROTO_IP means raw IP, and you probably don't want it. (Though you don't need to construct the IP header, only the TCP header.) As for the documentation, try http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. So just to make sure, if I used (IPPROTO_IP) it means any protocol upward of IP must be constructed by me? So if I was using TCP i'd construct TCP heads, UDP, etc...?

Comment: Right. Plus, for TCP you'd have to implement your own handshaking, acknowledgements, retransmission, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a lot of Linux manual pages describing socket:

- [SOCKET](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html)
- [IP](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html)
- [TCP](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html)
- [UDP](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/udp.7.html)
- [UNIX](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html)

In general, we use these arguments for `socket`:

1. Address family: `AF_INET` for internet domain address family, `AF_UNIX` for UNIX domain address family.
2. Socket type: `SOCK_STREAM` for TCP, `SOCK_DGRAM` for UDP. Of course you can use `SOCK_RAW` for directly access IP protocol.
3. Protocol: when using TCP or UDP, leave it to 0 is just fine; when using RAW, you can specify protocol to 0, IPPROTO_TCP for TCP sockets, IPPROTO_UDP for UDP sockets.

And, `SO_` means "socket option", `SOL_` means "socket option level", which are used to set socket options through `setsockopt` (also mentioned in [SOCKET](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html)).

In fact, you can find more pages at the bottom of these pages in the `SEE ALSO` section. Note that the page of 2 or 3 is a concrete system call or library function, pages of 7 is what you need.